# send request as user from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get google search results using  google extension, but I after few request I get captcha cause google cause I'm sending requests as a bot

is there any way to send get request as user  I can't set header the request wont 
work  I don't know why

The function I'm using to get search results

```
 function loadXMLDoc(theURL)
    {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, SeaMonkey
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Host', 'www.google.com');


        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {

                get_data = xmlhttp.responseText;

            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", theURL, false);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

);

I tried to add headers

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('X-Alt-Referer', 'https://www.google.com');
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Host', 'www.google.com');
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36');
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate, sdch');
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Accept-Language', 'en,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6');
```

But I get nothing   I think changing headers is blocked in chrome or something

is there any way to send request as user  so I don't get block after few searches.

Comment: Google is detecting that you're sending too many requests.  You can't avoid that.

Comment: @SLaks but I get blocked after few request  like 5 requests, but when I do it from my browsers I can do it up to 50  or even 100

Comment: Things you can try:

Put a delay in between requests to avoid looking like a spammer.
Use [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#exponential-backoff).
Try [Batching requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/batch#format-of-a-batch-request)
Those links uses Drive API as a sample but you get the idea - slow down.